# CSS 100% width when scrollbar appears AFTER render

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="my-div" style="width: 100%">
        <!-- Lots of stuff -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

By default, the height of the page is less than the window height, and the width comes out fine.

However, there's some JavaScript that can add content into my-div.
And then the page height becomes greater than the window height.
And then the scrollbar appears on the side of the page (which is fine).
...
And THEN the page remains the exact same width, and **doesn't shrink to accommodate the new scrollbar** (which is not fine, because the newly-added scrollbar blocks some content (don't ask why there's no padding...)).

If I reload the page with the extra content there, the content does shrink, which is good.

More info:

- Happens in Google Chrome.
- Happens in IE11.
- Doesn't happen in previous versions of IE.
- Messing around with `overflow` doesn't seem to help so far.
- Putting a permanent scrollbar is out of the question :)

So... how to fix?

Comment: Add a JSFiddle please

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com/) with your markup and css???

Comment: @BeatAlex Can jsfiddle fill the whole page?

Comment: Just the required bits @JacobSpire

Comment: @BeatAlex Bug not repeated in jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Sq9sv/1/embedded/result/ http://jsfiddle.net/Sq9sv/1/

Comment: Then it's something to do with the code you haven't provided.

Comment: The entire project is several MBs... I ain't putting it all here :) I put what I found to be relevant.